# I am looking for large nfc type 2 tags

Tags: tags, forum, nfc

I am looking to buy large nfc forum type 2 tags. At least 512 bytes, but preferably the largest 2040 byte tags that are theoretically possible according to the Nfc Forum Tag Type 2 specification. Does anybody know where I can purchase these large tags?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest buying a Mifare Classic 4K tag or sticker.

Search for "Mifare 4K" on Google.  Any contactless card or sticker you find should work, at least for testing purposes.

Comment: I am building a reader to read all four of the nfc forum tag types. I want to test my reader with the maximum tag size to make sure it works properly. As far as I know the Mifare Classic 4K is not compatible with the Type 2 tag type so it won't help me to test my type 2 reader code.

Comment: Is it a software (android?) reader or hardware?  If software, maybe you can fire off a fake or emulated tag that follows type 2 with extended data?  Does't help if you're creating a hardware reader of course.